# Why chart.js on meteor.js rebuilds itself instead of interpolate new point?

Tags: javascript, meteor, chart.js

I'm playing with chart.js on meteor, and want to create real-time updating chart.

So I have a data array on server, which increases every 5 seconds.

This is how my chart is behave( it's rebuilds each time ) : https://youtu.be/PEu07KfEyUc

And here is what I was expected :
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line-point-data.html ( press add data )

Here is my code:

charts.html

```
<template name="chart1"> <canvas id="Chart1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>  {{graphsBuild}} </template>
```

charts.js

```
  Template.chart1.helpers({
graphsBuild: function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
var datu = Meteor.user().addinfo.graphCharge;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: datu,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'amount: ',
      data: datu,
      fill: false,
      steppedLine: false,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'easeInQuad',
      borderColor: [
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {}
  }); } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found that I need to call an update() method, to update charts!
More info in documentation: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Can you please show the code how you achieved it instead of providing link.